# How can you use multiple lookaheads in RegEx on the same part of the string?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to solve the fourth day of the [Advent of Code 2019](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/4)

I decided to do it with regular expression and started by limiting the amount of numbers to exactly 6 digits. Next, I have to make sure the digits are increasing from left to right.

So far so good, I managed to do this with the following RegEx:

```
^(?=^\d{6}$)0*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$
```

Now, I want to go one step further and add a second condition (two adjacent digits like "22" somewhere in the 6 digit number). My following snippet is working on its own, but when integrating it in my previous RegEx as a lookahead, it isn't.

```
(\d)\1
```

Now, my integrated version that, for some reason I don't know, isn't working.

```
^(?=^\d{6}$)(?=(\d)\1)0*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$
```

What's wrong with this? How would it be possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lookahead insists that the matching digits are at the beginning of the string since it comes immediately after `^`. You need to allow for other digits beforehand i.e. `(?=\d*(\d)\1)` or in total

```
^(?=\d{6}$)(?=\d*(\d)\1)0*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/piQSID/6)